# Running gradlew assembleRelease produces no output APK

Tags: android, gradle, apk

Whenever I run `gradlew assembleRelease` either from a terminal or from within Android Studio, I see that the process ends successfully with "BUILD SUCCESSFUL". But after inspecting `app\build\outputs` I don't see any folder named `apk`.

Using the same build variant "release", the application can be installed into the device directly from Android Studio and the apk can also be successfully generated when using the "Generate Signed Bundle / APK..." option from the IDE.

I am using gradle 7.2.0.

- Where should I look for to understand what is happening?
- What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: I don't know why it's changed while the documentation still haven't changed. It's under app/build/intermediates/apk now

Comment: I tried to install the apk from intermediates in a different device and it failed installation. I read somewhere in google groups that they had in fact fixed long time ago a behavior where intermediate build specific apks were being left in build/outputs instead of intermediate and they had decided to change the location of intermediate files.

Comment: It was changed. but in the latest AS update I encountered this problem too. it seems they've changed it back or probably it's a bug and will be fixed in the next update

Comment: If the apk didn't get installed there's probably something wrong with your `gradle.build` file. in the `buildTypes` section inside `release` add these: `zipAlignEnabled true` and `shrinkResources true` and `minifyEnabled true`. if this didn't fix try to update the gradle plugin

Comment: Also check if you are running `assembleRelease` on the module not the entire project. in the gradle pannel on the right under your project expand the `app` then under that expand `tasks->other` then choose the `assembleRelease`

Comment: Any luck with this yet? I've been hit by this bug too. I updated to patch 3 of Android Studio 2021.1.1, but it's still happening.

Comment: None yet. Problem is still present and ran out of ideas to test